# SOSL for self lookup fields

Tags: apex, lookup, sosl

`Region__c` is the self lookup on `Agent__c`. One region have many agents. When searchString = region name, it displays only one record.

I want to display all Agents in that region. How to achieve this?

```
String searchquery = 'FIND \'*' + searchString + '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Agent__c (Region__c,Region__r.name, Manager__c, Manager__r.name,Name), user( id, Name) limit 1999';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create Agent custom object and self lookup field name Region. Below query is 
working fine for me and giving expected results -

```
FIND {test} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Agent__c (Region__c,Region__r.name, Name)
```

Here test is the name of record.